searchbar and appbar not visible on the screen
I am trying to run flutter app but the appbar and the search button is not visible on the screen and anything added under the TPrimaryHeaderContainerWidget isn't visible though the TPrimaryHeaderContainerWidget is visible
this is the code for home.dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
      children: [
        TPrimaryHeaderContainer(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            THomeBar(),
             SizedBox(height: TSizes.spaceBtwSections),

          ],
        ))
      ],
    )));
  }
}

this is the TPrimaryHeader class
class TPrimaryHeaderContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const TPrimaryHeaderContainer({
    super.key, required this.child,
  });

  final Widget? child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TCurvedEdgeWidget(
      child:Container(
          color:TColors.primary,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
          child:SizedBox(
            height:400,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(top:-150, right: -250, child: TCircularWidget(background: TColors.textWhite.withOpacity(0.1),)),
                Positioned(top:100, right: -300, child: TCircularWidget(background: TColors.textWhite.withOpacity(0.1),))
              ],
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}

this is the homebar class
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
      children: [
        TPrimaryHeaderContainer(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            THomeBar(),
             SizedBox(height: TSizes.spaceBtwSections),

          ],
        ))
      ],
    )));
  }
}


Single Child Scrol View always Comes in side a Container or sizedBox with defined Height
try Changing this
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(...),
  body: SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      // ... your content here
    ),
  ),
),

